# Manifest merger failed: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 10

Tags: android

Manifest merger failed: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 10 declared in library [com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1]

Comment: It seems that the library `com.amulyakhare.textdrawable` requires a higher minimum SDK. Change it to 10 or search for another library.

Comment: thanks but if i may ask how can i change it to 10 or search for another library

Answer (score 2):

This error happened because you included a library which has minSdkVersion=10.

I can see from [here](https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable/blob/master/library/build.gradle)

However, you project is set to minSdkVersion=8

To fix, I think you should change your build.gradle and apply same setting of the library that you included:

Search for lines below in your build.gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    ...
 }
```

And change to

```
 defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    ...
 }
```